# Failed to update Salesforce account because of DUPLICATES_DETECTED error even with Allow setting in Duplicate Rule

Tags: duplicate-management, jsforce

I'm using [JSforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) to integrate Salesforce into my app. When I update a Salesforce account from my end via JSforce update function, it got **DUPLICATES_DETECTED** error because Salesforce considers this account is duplicate with another one. Although I set **Allow** in Duplicate rule setting of the Salesforce page and we can edit successfully this account on it, It cannot be done via API (with using JSforce) from my end because of this error. Is this possible to bypass Duplicate Management via JSforce without disabling these rules?

```
   const jsforce = require('jsforce');

   /* Update to Salesforce */
   update: function (updateObject, callback) {
     this.getSObject().update(updateObject, callback);
   }
```

Here is my setting on Salesforce Duplicate Rules section
[image]

Some documents suggest setting **allowSave** to true in header of request via API soap like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_duplicateruleheader.htm) but I don't use API soap, I'm using JSforce instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have enabled Alert, you are getting the `DUPLICATES_DETECTED` message.  The Allow option means that when the user sees the alert, they are also given the option to continue and create the record anyway.

EDIT: To use the Allow option for SOAP calls, you should use the `allowSave` option in [`DuplicateRuleHeader`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_duplicateruleheader.htm).  For Apex, use [`DMLOptionsHeader`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm).

Comment: Thanks, your opinion helps me a lot. I just wonder why Salesforce has an option **allowSave** in DuplicateRuleHeader in this document [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_duplicateruleheader.htm) Does this doc use for people who work with SOAP API directly to integrate with SF? I just confuse how they implement via SOAP API directly. Btw, I'm using js instead of java.

Comment: Ah that is new to me, that should work, but I'm not familiar with making SOAP calls.  Please [edit] your post to include your SOAP call detail and how you are using DuplicateRuleHeader.